# Using Sentry in Chrome Extension Background script not wroking

Tags: javascript, webpack, google-chrome-extension, sentry

I have checked the official sentry docs and I have also checked out some other references but I can't find a solution...

Basically I am trying to install sentry in my browser extension.

So in my **background.js** I have done the following

import * as Sentry from '@sentry/browser';

```
Sentry.init({
  dsn: '...'
});
```

but... this isn't doing anything? - and it also seems to stop the rest of my code working, for example:

I have the following code in my background.js

```
chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener((tabId, changeInfo, tab) => {
    if (changeInfo.status === 'complete') {
      currentTab = tab;
      console.log(tab);
    }
  });
```

Now If I comment out the sentry init this code works as expected, but as soon as I put the sentry init back in, this code no longer runs.

I'm getting no errors, and I can't find any real examples of how to implement sentry with a browser extension. Now I know it's possible but I'm clearly doing something wrong?

Comment: To be able to use `import` statement you either need a compiler/bundler that's capable of handling the modules correctly (check your webpack config) or switch to a background page html and declare your scripts as modules, see [this](https://medium.com/front-end-weekly/es6-modules-in-chrome-extensions-an-introduction-313b3fce955b), but native modules don't support `@sentry/browser` syntax so you'll have to use a different bundle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I seem to have found the solution to my problem I was using a webpack to bundle my chrome-extension with required dependencies. Webpack was generating a vendor.js file which contained all the imported dependencies. 
In my case, the mistake I did was not adding that file the as scripts in the manifest.json file.

```
...
      "background": {
        "matches": ["https://*/*"],
        "scripts": ["js/vendor.js","js/background.js"],
        "persistent": true
      },
...
```

This resolved the issue as the dependencies are now loading correctly.